# regex to pull in number with decimal or comma

Tags: ruby, regex

This is my line of code:

```
col_value = line_item[column].scan(/\d+./).join().to_i
```

When I enter 30,000 into the textfield, col_value is 30.
I want it to bring in any number:
30,000
30.5
30.55
30000

Any of these are valid...

Is there a problem with the scan and or join which would cause it to return 30?  Using the suggested regexes below still retunrs 30 e.g.

```
col_value = line_item[column].scan(/\d+[,.]?\d+/).join().to_i
```

Could it be that "`to_i`" converts "30,000" to 30??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `"30,000".to_i #=> 30"`. See [String#to_i](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-to_i): "Extraneous characters past the end of a valid number are ignored."

I suggest you first remove the commas, then apply a regex:

```
R = /
    \d+      # match >= 0 digits
    |        # or
    \d+\.\d+ # match > 0 digits, a decimal point, then > 0 digits
    /x       # extended mode

str = "30,000 30.5 30.55 30000 1. .1"
str1 = str.tr(',','')
  #=> "30000 30.5 30.55 30000 1. .1" 
a = str1.scan(R)
  #=> ["30000", "30", "5", "30", "55", "30000"] 
a.map(&:to_i)
  #=> [30000, 30, 5, 30, 55, 30000]
```

After chaining, we have:

```
str.tr(',','').scan(R).map(&:to_i)
```

If the desired solution is instead:

```
  #=> [30000, 30, 5, 30, 55, 30000, 1, 0]
```

the regex needs to be modified as follows:

```
R = /
    \d+      # match >= 0 digits
    |        # or
    \d+\.\d+ # match > 0 digits, a decimal point, then > 0 digits
    |        # or
    \d+\.    # match > 0 digits, then a decimal point
    |        # or
    \.\d+    # match a decimal point, then > 0 digits
    /x       # extended mode
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex will match you desired output:

```
\d+[,.]?\d*
```

here `?` is used as optional to match.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kJ9zB5/1)

Comment: how do you test something like 30.5.5.5?

Comment: for that you can check a single number at a time using `^\d+[.,]?\d+$`. If you use this regex this will not match your input 30.5.5.5 but it will 3.05 OR 3000 OR 30,120

Comment: user3437721, `30.5.5.5` clearly cannot be interpreted as a single number, and if you mean it to represent several numbers, is it `30.5 5.5` or `3 0.5 5.5`?

Comment: You still need to extract the integer, and `"1,000"[/\d+[,.]?\d*/].to_i #=> 1` won't do it. Also, your regex matches `"3."` and `".3"`. That may be fine, but the OP should be aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

```
\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?
```

Try this.This should do it for you.

Comment: Your first sentence should be "Yes.".

Comment: The OP wants to convert the string to an integer if it represents an integer, but `"30,000"[/\d+(?:[,.]\d+)/].to_i #=> 30`. You need to remove the comma, if one is present, before the conversion.